# 404 error with simple jsp page

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I've what looks like a rookie mistake but it seems like I can't get through it. I'm learning JSP and Spring, and I came across a 404 error with my project.
I'm using a tomcat 8.0 local server. My goal is to go from "http://localhost:8080/TestSpring/vues/bonjour.jsp" to "http://localhost:8080/TestSpring/bonjour" with the help of a tutorial but this leads to a 404.

"dispatcher-servlet.xml"

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="be.knoware" />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/vues/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="ISO-8859-1" />
</bean>
```

web.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC 
"-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN" 
"http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Declaration de la servlet de Spring et de son mapping -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>servlet-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>servlet-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

bonjour.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" isELIgnored="false"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title><spring:message code="titre.bonjour"/> ${personne}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <spring:message code="libelle.bonjour.lemonde" arguments="${personne}"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

BonjourController.java

```
package controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/bonjour")

public class BonjourController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String afficherBonjour(final ModelMap pModel){
        pModel.addAttribute("personne","Jim");
        return "bonjour";
    }
}
```

And if it might help, the project.

[image]

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Is your application successfully deployed in server?

Comment: @Subodh Yes, I think so (if this is what you mean by deployed [link](http://imgur.com/AOrBi8l) ) and there is the console text when  my server start and I try to connect to the URL. [link](http://pastebin.com/zvXLQfn7)

Comment: In log it will clearly show the project is deployed or not

Comment: So my log file in the tomcat directory are empty, but since I can access "http://localhost:8080/TestSpring/vues/bonjour.jsp" and it displays the information I guess it's deployed.

Comment: As i know you not deployed your project directly in Tomcat you are running it from some ide so IDE will show you log in console

Comment: I think that I might do a clean install of tomcat.. when I try to reach localhost:8080 it is a 404 error too.

Answer (score 1):

You Can do Some Steps if there is some Deploy Problem or Server Problem

- Clean and Build the project and copy the war file in to your Server
- Before update war file you have to shutdown tomcat or Server.
- Start the Server and Open URL and Check war extract automatic or not if yes then there is no problem of Server .
- Check URL and Logs file for Better assurance.
  Happy to Help

Comment: So thanks to you I found how to check if deployed, It was actually deployed :)

Answer (score 1):

well as i notice in comments , they have a point quessing if your app is being deployed properly or not , because your web.xml does not look so valid.

i) 
This is only to be used when you want to pass a global application context to all your servlets , with this configuration its like you are loading the spring-context twice.
you can find more info in [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-servlet)

```
 <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

so if you dont want to pass a global appContext , then remove the below lines from your web.xml

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

ii)

in servlet mapping change the url pattern from / to /*
so it ll be like :

```
 <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>servlet-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

iii)
in your dispatcher-servlet.xml add the package where the controller is 
cause its not being handled by spring

```
<context:component-scan base-package="controller" />
```

Answer (score 1):

In XML-based MultiActionController, you have to configure the method name resolver (InternalPathMethodNameResolver, PropertiesMethodNameResolver or ParameterMethodNameResolver) to map the URL to a particular method name.

First of all can you try add your Controller bean to dispatcher-servlet.xml;

```
<!-- Register the bean -->
<bean class="yourPackage.controller.BonjourController " />
```

If it is not work try ViewResolvers.

Answer (score 0):

So, in the end it was a misunderstanding from me. In fact, I was using the wrong base-package in my dispatcher-servlet.xml... At least this post taught me some good habits in J2E and how to cfg tomcat !

Anyway, thx for your time :)